Привязка к событию через Interaction EventTrigger завершается позже чем возникает само событие
Допустим есть ViewModel с двумя свойствами, и командами обрабатывающими загрузку формы и изменение текста:
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string TestString { get; set; } = "";

    public string TestString2 { get; set; } = "";

    private RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> _loadedCommand;

    public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> LoadedCommand =>
        _loadedCommand ??= new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(Loaded);

    private RelayCommand _textChangedCommand;

    public RelayCommand TextChangedCommand =>
        _textChangedCommand ??= new RelayCommand(TextChanged);


    private void Loaded(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestString = "Loaded";
    }

    private void TextChanged()
    {
        TestString2 = "Modified";
    }
}

XAML формы:
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp.Views.MyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:WpfApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:MyViewModel}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1200">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TestString}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestString2}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

У TextBlock должен поменяться текст на "Modified", но этого не происходит потому что привязка устанавливается слишком долго, в итоге событие TextChanged возникает раньше чем завершится привязка к нему.
Надпись "Modified" появляется если добавить задержку:
private async void Loaded(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    TestString = "Loaded";
}

Есть ли красивый способ решить эту проблему?


У вас нету MVVM, ибо всякие RoutedEventArgs - это View слой, а вы их пихаете в VM. 2. Зачем вам тут "Интерактивность"? Loaded - это конструктор VM класса, ибо обычно делается как? DataContext = new VM(), другими словами, загружена VM, загружен и V слой (правда бывают исключения). TextChanged - об этом вам говорит привязанное свойство, вы можете в его set указать все, что хотите и это будет вызываться при изменении свойства. Вердикт: Вы перемудрили.


По поводу использования сеттера я вас понял, но вот по поводу Loaded не совсем. Вы предлагаете все действия по загрузке начальных данных (из Api) выполнять в конструкторе VM, не дожидаясь загрузки V?
Просто у нас сначала идет DataContext = new VM(); и на следующей строке InitializeComponent();, соответственно вполне может возникнуть ситуация при которой данные загружены а форма ещё нет, либо я чего-то не понимаю.
Если вас не затруднит можете ли вы дать ссылку на проект WPF с использованием MVVM, который вы бы советовали как эталонный, что бы я смог его изучить?

"по загрузке начальных данных (из Api)" - Не пойму я конечно зачем вам это, ну да ладно... Если вам нужен прям тонки контроль над окном, то яб сделал так: Интерфейс в котором будут нужные события, допусти interface IWIndowVM { void OnLoaded(); }, далее, в классе окна что-то по типу if (DataContext is IWindowVM vm) { Loaded += (s, e) => vm.OnLoaded(); }, ну и в VM соответственно будет class VM : IWindowVM { void OnLoaded(){ Debug.WriteLine("Window Loaded") } }.

Триггер для TextChangedCommand - в чём смысл? Есть же привязка.
<TextBox Text="{Binding TestString}">

Берём свойство
private string _testString = "";

public string TestString
{
   get => _testString;
   set
   {
       _testString = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
       TextChangedCommand.Execute();
   }
};

А триггер из XAML выбрасываем.
